# Integrate networkx in eclipse on windows

Tags: python, eclipse, networkx

I'm using PyDev in eclipse with Python 2.7 on windows 7. I Installed networkx and it is properly running within Python shell but in eclipse it is showing error as it is unable to locate networkx can anyone tell me how to remove this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to rebuild your interpreter

go to project > properties > pyDev-Interpreter/Grammar

click the "click here to configure"

remove the existing interpreter

hit "Auto config" button and follow the prompts

kind of a pain but the only way Ive found to autodiscover newly installed packages

Comment: If you manually add it to your projects python path that would also resolve ... but you would need to do it for every project that used it ...

Comment: It works fine but i think some methods are not being detected like if I execute nx.draw(G) then it shows error that 'module'has no method named draw()...is networkx has some issues with windows?

Comment: naw its probably implemented at a C interface level or something in which case it wont get picked up sometimes...
Its hard to say ... but in my experience networkX has just worked on windows... is it actually giving an error? or is it just eclipse thats giving the error

Comment: networkx.lanl doesn't have updated version for windows..I installed version 0.3 seems this version doesn't have draw() method where can I get updated version for windows?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two options:

1. Rebuild your interpreter
2. Add it to your python path by appending the location of networkx to `sys.path` in python